# CountVectorizer gives incompatible row dimensions error in scikit-learn with heterogeneous columns

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, countvectorizer

In the data below, it has heterogeneous data types (numerical, categorical, and string-list) as features. The predicted variable is `DISEASE`.

I am using `CountVectorizer` to transform the string-list, and I created a class `RavelTransformer` which flattens a 2-D column into a 1-D format before `CountVectorizer` can use it.

This is a working example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, GridSearchCV
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline, make_pipeline
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC, SVC
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

class RavelTransformer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        return X.ravel()

data = {
    'AGE': [39, np.nan, 21, 13, 45, 26, np.nan, 48],
    'URBAN': ['urban', np.nan, 'urban', 'rural', 'urban', 'rural', 'urban', 'urban'],
    'NAME': ['jack', 'juste', 'ann', np.nan, 'jack', 'gil', 'jack', 'justo'],
    'SUBSTRING_1L': ['j, a, c, k', 'j, u, s, t, e', 'a, n', '', 'j, a, c, k', 'g, i, l', 'j, a, c, k', 'j, u, s, t, o'],
    'SUBSTRING_4L': ['jack', 'just, uste', '', '', 'jack', '', 'jack', 'just, usto'],
    'SUBSTRING_5L': ['', 'juste', '', '', '', '', '', 'justo'],
    'DISEASE': ['cancer', 'healthy', 'healthy', 'healthy', 'cancer', 'healthy', 'cancer', 'heart'],
    }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    df[['AGE', 'NAME', 'URBAN','SUBSTRING_4L']], df['DISEASE'], test_size=0.50, random_state=3)

transformer_num = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='median')),
    ('scaler', StandardScaler())])

transformer_cat = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='constant', fill_value='')),
    ('onehotencoder', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'))])

transformer_ngram = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='constant', fill_value='')),
    ('ravel', RavelTransformer()),
    ('countvectorizer', CountVectorizer(analyzer='word', tokenizer=None, preprocessor=None, stop_words=None, 
        max_features=5000))])

preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ('num', transformer_num, ['AGE']),
        ('cat', transformer_cat, ['NAME', 'URBAN']),
        ('ngram', transformer_ngram, ['SUBSTRING_4L']),
        ])

ml_algo = LogisticRegression(solver='lbfgs', multi_class='ovr', max_iter=4000)
model = make_pipeline(preprocessor, ml_algo)
model.fit(x_train, y_train)

print(x_train, '\n'*2, y_train)
print()
print(x_test, '\n'*2, y_test)
print()
print('Model score (on training set): %.3f' % model.score(x_train, y_train))
print('Model score (on test set): %.3f' % model.score(x_test, y_test))
```

`SUBSTRING_4L` and `SUBSTRING_5L` works fine on their own if only one of them is included as a feature.

But when I tried to include them both:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, GridSearchCV
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline, make_pipeline
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC, SVC
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

class RavelTransformer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        return X.ravel()

data = {
    'AGE': [39, np.nan, 21, 13, 45, 26, np.nan, 48],
    'URBAN': ['urban', np.nan, 'urban', 'rural', 'urban', 'rural', 'urban', 'urban'],
    'NAME': ['jack', 'juste', 'ann', np.nan, 'jack', 'gil', 'jack', 'justo'],
    'SUBSTRING_1L': ['j, a, c, k', 'j, u, s, t, e', 'a, n', '', 'j, a, c, k', 'g, i, l', 'j, a, c, k', 'j, u, s, t, o'],
    'SUBSTRING_4L': ['jack', 'just, uste', '', '', 'jack', '', 'jack', 'just, usto'],
    'SUBSTRING_5L': ['', 'juste', '', '', '', '', '', 'justo'],
    'DISEASE': ['cancer', 'healthy', 'healthy', 'healthy', 'cancer', 'healthy', 'cancer', 'heart'],
    }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    df[['AGE', 'NAME', 'URBAN','SUBSTRING_4L', 'SUBSTRING_5L']], df['DISEASE'], test_size=0.50, random_state=3)

transformer_num = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='median')),
    ('scaler', StandardScaler())])

transformer_cat = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='constant', fill_value='')),
    ('onehotencoder', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'))])

transformer_ngram = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='constant', fill_value='')),
    ('ravel', RavelTransformer()),
    ('countvectorizer', CountVectorizer(analyzer='word', tokenizer=None, preprocessor=None, stop_words=None, 
        max_features=5000))])

preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ('num', transformer_num, ['AGE']),
        ('cat', transformer_cat, ['NAME', 'URBAN']),
        ('ngram', transformer_ngram, ['SUBSTRING_4L', 'SUBSTRING_5L']),
        ])

ml_algo = LogisticRegression(solver='lbfgs', multi_class='ovr', max_iter=4000)
model = make_pipeline(preprocessor, ml_algo)
model.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

I get this error `ValueError: blocks[0,:] has incompatible row dimensions. Got blocks[0,2].shape[0] == 8, expected 4.`.

---

Edit

I modified the code a bit so that `SUBSTRING_4L` and `SUBSTRING_5L` are handled separately, but still within the same pipeline. This doesn't give any error.

```
preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ('num', transformer_num, ['AGE']),
        ('cat', transformer_cat, ['NAME', 'URBAN']),
        ('ngram_4l', transformer_ngram, ['SUBSTRING_4L']),
        ('ngram_5l', transformer_ngram, ['SUBSTRING_5L']),
        ])
```

But would someone help confirm this is correct? Or point me to the direction of how to confirm if this is error-free?

Comment: any idea what causes this error or why your solution works?
transformer_ngram is sent twice to two columns. I suggest to clone it before so the vocabulary might be different.